# How to get clipboard content with Python3 & GDK 4?

Tags: python-3.x, gdk, gtk4

[GTK4 doens't manage the Clipboard](https://docs.gtk.org/gtk4/migrating-3to4.html#replace-gtkclipboard-with-gdkclipboard) anymore, now it's [done from GDK4](https://docs.gtk.org/gdk4/class.Clipboard.html).

I was not lucky migrating this code from GTK3 to GDK4?

```
from gi.repository import Gtk, Gdk
cb = Gtk.Clipboard.get(Gdk.SELECTION_CLIPBOARD)
content = cb.wait_for_text()
```

Any idea please? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I'm similarly stuck.

Comment: Hi @Reece No, I didn't get a way to do it work. I'll wait a little more and search into the code of GitHub... probably there will be something useful in a few months. Best regards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally figured this out. Here's a complete function to copy the clipboard to a file in a Nautilus plugin (see [nautilus-image-copypaste](https://github.com/reece/nautilus-image-copypaste/blob/main/src/nautilus-image-copypaste.py)):

```
def get_clipboard():
    clipboard = Gdk.Display().get_default().get_clipboard()
    _logger.warning("Clipboard: " + clipboard.get_formats().to_string())
    return clipboard

def copy_clipboard_to_file_image(self, menuitem: Nautilus.MenuItem, dir):
    clipboard = get_clipboard()

    def update_cb(so, res, user_data):
        texture = clipboard.read_texture_finish(res)
        pixbuf = Gdk.pixbuf_get_from_texture(texture)
        ts = datetime.datetime.utcnow().strftime("%FT%T")
        filename = os.path.join(dir, f"Clipboard {ts}.png")
        pixbuf.savev(filename, "png", (), ())
        _logger.warning(f"Pasted to {filename}")

    clipboard.read_texture_async(
        cancellable=None, callback=update_cb, user_data=None
    )
```

This is for textures, but there are similar mechanisms for text or other content.  Clipboard handling changed immensely between Gtk/Gdk 3 and 4. The major changes: 1) Clipboard moved from Gtk to Gdk, 2) The Gdk 4 clipboard requires callbacks.

I did *not* figure out how to do the reverse, i.e., set the clipboard from a texture. For that, I opened [How do I set the clipboard with a Texture in Gdk4 using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75356877/how-do-i-set-the-clipboard-with-a-texture-in-gdk4-using-python).

Answer (score 0):

`Gtk.Widget` has a method [`get_clipboard()`](https://docs.gtk.org/gtk4/method.Widget.get_clipboard.html) to get the clipboard.

The clipboard has a method [`read_text_async`](https://docs.gtk.org/gdk4/method.Clipboard.read_text_async.html), which is called with a callback
that is supposed to call `read_text_finished`.

```
widget: Gtk.Widget = ...
clipboard = widget.get_clipboard()

def callback(cb, res):
    try:
        text = cb.read_text_finished(cb, res)
    except GLib.GError:  # Errors occur often
        pass
    else:
        ...
clipboard.read_text_async(None, callback)
```

The suggested method in the migration guide is
`Gdk.Clipboard.get_content()`, which returns a [`GdkContentProvider`](https://docs.gtk.org/gdk4/class.ContentProvider.html), but this content is empty if the copied text does not come from within the application. Furthermore,
I have not gotten it to work with Python, maybe because the method `GdkContentProvider.get_value` has an in-out-parameter.