# How do I set the clipboard with a Texture in Gdk4 using Python?

Tags: gtk, pygobject, gdk, nautilus

[nautilus-image-copypaste](https://github.com/reece/nautilus-image-copypaste) is a Nautilus extension that allows users to set the clipboard from image files and to create image files from the clipboard.  Reading the clipboard works, however I can't figure out how to set the clipboard [at line 108](https://github.com/reece/nautilus-image-copypaste/blob/main/src/nautilus-image-copypaste.py#L108).

The Python Gdk4 bindings do not have the [set_texture](https://docs.gtk.org/gdk4/method.Clipboard.set_texture.html) method, which would have been the obvious choice.

The [set](https://docs.gtk.org/gdk4/method.Clipboard.set.html) method, which is available in the bindings, requires a GType (GDK_TYPE_TEXTURE), but I've been unable find that in the bindings.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
texture = Gdk.Texture.new_from_filename('/path/to/image.jpg')
png_bytes = texture.save_to_png_bytes()
content_provider = Gdk.ContentProvider.new_for_bytes('image/png', png_bytes)
Gdk.Display.get_default().get_clipboard().set_content(content_provider)
```